# Include Intervention Image to a Wordpress theme programmatically (without the use of plugins)

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, intervention

While trying to use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) with a Wordpress Theme I am creating I getting some errors. Here is code I have in single-myposttype.php:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 

use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;


Image::configure(array('driver' => 'GD'));

$image_path = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'myprefix_thephoto', true ); // I have an image folder in root of wp that I don't want in wp-content



// print($image_path); die; // if uncommented this will print '/images/test_img.jpg' as it should



$image = Image::make($image_path)->resize(300, 200); // but this way it generate an error

print($image); die;
```

Is this the correct way? What Am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I am getting this error message in the browser:

Fatal error: Uncaught Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException: Image source not readable in /Users/hailton/Sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/wp-mustage/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:346 Stack trace: #0 /Users/hailton/Sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/wp-mustage/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDriver.php(66): Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder->init('/images/test_im...') #1 /Users/hailton/Sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/wp-mustage/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageManager.php(54): Intervention\Image\AbstractDriver->init('/images/test_im...') #2 /Users/hailton/Sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/wp-mustage/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageManagerStatic.php(58): Intervention\Image\ImageManager->make('/images/test_im...') #3 /Users/hailton/Sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/wp-mustage/single-membro.php(24): Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::make('/images/test_im...') #4 /Users/hailton/Site in /Users/hailton/Sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/wp-mustage/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php on line 346

Comment: What errors especifically are you getting? Please update your question and include them so we can help you debug.

Comment: sorry @cabrerahector. I forgot to include the error from the browser. I've updated the question.

Comment: Intervention is telling you that it can't read the image. Make sure the folder where it's stored is readable (and that the image is too.)

Comment: In Finder, the permission is set to read/write for the user(me). For staff and everyone it's set to read only.  Maybe something interfering... I'll check.